# AWS Route 53 - Get hosted zone by domain name?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-php-sdk

Is there a way to retrieve a Hosted Zone by Domain Name ?

I thought using listHostedZonesByName( 'pagefoo.io' ) would do the trick, but it returns unrelated results: pagefoo.net, pagefoo.org instead of just pagefoo.io.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => /hostedzone/XXXXXXXXXXXX
            [Name] => pagefoo.io.
            [CallerReference] => XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
            [Config] => Array
                (
                    [PrivateZone] => 
                )

            [ResourceRecordSetCount] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => /hostedzone/XXXXXXXXXXXX
            [Name] => pagefoo.net.
            [CallerReference] => XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
            [Config] => Array
                (
                    [PrivateZone] => 
                )

            [ResourceRecordSetCount] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Id] => /hostedzone/XXXXXXXXXXXX
            [Name] => pagefoo.org.
            [CallerReference] => XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
            [Config] => Array
                (
                    [PrivateZone] => 
                )

            [ResourceRecordSetCount] => 4
        )

)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the aws-cli route53 interface, I called [list-hosted-zones-by-name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/list-hosted-zones-by-name.html). It returned all of my zones.

```
$ aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name
{
    "HostedZones": [
        (lots of output here)
    ], 
    "IsTruncated": false, 
    "MaxItems": "100"
}
```

I then added `--dns-name domain.com` to the query and it returned the one result as I expected:

```
$ aws route53 list-hosted-zones-by-name --dns-name domain.com
{
    "HostedZones": [
        {
            "ResourceRecordSetCount": 7, 
            "CallerReference": "12345abcde", 
            "Config": {
                "Comment": "HostedZone created by Route53 Registrar", 
                "PrivateZone": false
            }, 
            "Id": "/hostedzone/AABBCCDD", 
            "Name": "domain.com."
        }
    ], 
    "DNSName": "domain.com", 
    "IsTruncated": false, 
    "MaxItems": "100"
}
```

You didn't say what language you are using, but the calls are all similar, since it's an API response. If you need help with a specific SDK you should include the language and the code for calling it. But assuming your output is from Javascript, [it looks like this is the proper call](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Route53.html#listHostedZonesByName-property):

```
route53.listHostedZonesByName({ DNSName: 'domain.com' }, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I'm trying, in PHP:$result = $this->route53->listHostedZonesByName( [ 'DNSName' => 'pagefoo.io' ] );
But it returns a subset of my hosted zones, instead of a single one. I guess I don't understand how this command works.

Comment: It seems like AWS is missing something, but this one api can be used in a number of ways.   If you search for the domain name, with a max items of 1, it will return the one you want; or if it doesn't exist, it will return ... something else.   If you need to tell if it exists, just compare what was returned with what you asked for.